# vs code extension develop. hellow world can't run

Tags: vscode-extensions

I follow the https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension tutorial, but when i came to "Then, inside the editor, press F5. This will compile and run the extension in a new Extension Development Host window." .I got a "building..." and nothing else.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUuth.png)

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I had the same problem, I just updated vscode and that fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your launch.json inside the .vscode has configuration like following:

```
{
            "name": "Run Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
        }
```

Also, try by re-installing all the packages before running F5.

Comment: Thansk for your answers. I have the configuration,

Comment: What packages should i re-installing?